# How to read from an EDB database file

Tags: windows, nuget, edb

Microsoft Edge and other Microsoft products use an Extensible Storage Engine. If you have edge installed on windows, you can find the database file here:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_xxxxxxx\AC
\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\DataStore\Data\nouser1\xxxxxxxx\DBStore\spartan.edb
```

I would like to read this database from my .NET app.

The only tool I have seen for viewing this data appears to be deprecated:

```
http://www.woanware.co.uk/forensics/esedbviewer.html
```

I can't seem to find any relevant nuget packages for querying this type of database. Does anyone have experience working with this type of database?

Answer (score 2):

The database engine is `esent.dll`, and you can access it in several different ways:

- C API. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269259(v=exchg.10).aspx
- C#. https://github.com/microsoft/managedesent
- Simplified C# (Isam layer). Easier to use, but not everything is exposed. https://github.com/Microsoft/ManagedEsent/tree/master/isam

(Disclosure: I've worked on the above products.)

That being said, if you just modify a random database, you can impact the host process's integrity, and it might end up crashing.

If you're a law-enforcement agent and it's for forensic purposes, Microsoft should be able to assist you (I haven't done it myself, but I've heard that they'll do it).

-martin